# RFC4821 PLPMTUD probe request

Tags: tcp, mtu

PLPMTUD - Packatization Layer Path MTU Discovery
Subsequently increasing MTU probe requests are sent to measure optimal MTU till one fails. 
Does the probe request contain actual data to be sent? OR is it just like a dummy packet without any data in it?

Also, how does one differentiate between regular tcp packet and this probe packet?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

> The isolated loss of a probe packet (with or without an ICMP Packet Too Big message) is treated as an indication of an MTU limit, and not as a congestion indicator.  In this case alone, the Packetization Protocol is permitted to retransmit any missing data without adjusting the congestion window.

As those probe messages are reliable (entirely delivered) and large enough. It makes no sense to send arbitrary data?!

**Answer**: Real data are sent.